# Function import in EF 6.0 does not work as intended

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that has 1 input parameter and 1 output parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_GetPackageStatus]

    @PackageName varchar(100),
    @status int output
AS

BEGIN

     SELECT TOP 1 @status = status from [SSISDB].[catalog].[executions]
     WHERE package_name = @PackageName + '.dtsx'
     ORDER by [execution_id] desc

END
```

---

I imported it as a function import into EF. But it always return -1 as output on debuging.
In EF context.cs file, stored procedure is converted to a function as below, even though in Model browser i have specified return type as None:

```
public virtual int p_GetPackageStatus(string packageName, ObjectParameter status)
{
    var packageNameParameter = packageName != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("PackageName", packageName) :
        new ObjectParameter("PackageName", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("p_GetPackageStatus", packageNameParameter, status);
}
```

In my c# code, I am using it in this way:

```
int status = db.p_GetPackageStatus(packageName, objectParameter);
```

Here I am always getting status as `-1` even though the stored procedure gives the correct result in SQL.
What could be the possible solution?

Comment: Have you included executions table in the edmx file? Also your function takes object parameter but where is it looking for? I'm guessing you need to include executions table and link this function to that

Comment: No, I have not include executions table in the edmx file. I doubt if its possible too as [catalog].[executions] is a view available in SSISDB database and not part of database i am using.
The code snippet i have provided is auto generated by visual studio, so i am not very sure of object parameter part.

Comment: I'm not sure about your database tables. But I know you can add views too in EF. You should update your database layout and all code probably